# Storing different ojects in a container that have been extended from the same abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance, casting, polymorphism, abstract-class

Is it possible to store different objects that have been extended from the same abstract object in a single container and be able to access all of the custom fields of those objects.  Let me present an example:
  Suppose I have two cars:  ford and honda.  Since all cars have weight and color, I could make the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class Car{

  private double weight; 
  private String color;

  public Car(){
    this.weight=0;
    this.color="";
  }
  ...getters and 
  ...setters
}
```

Now suppose my Ford class has an additional field '**radio**' and looks like this:

```
public Ford extends Car(){
private String radio;

public Ford(){
super();
this.radio = "generic";
}
}
```

Similarly, the Honda class has a custom field '**camera**'

```
public Honda extends Car(){
  private String camera;

  public Honda(){
    super();
    this.camera= "analog";
  }
}
```

Is it possible to keep the instances of these classes in a single container, something like the following below.  Please note the code below works but this is not quite what I want.  see comments below:

```
Ford ford = new Ford();
Honda honda = new Honda();
ArrayList<Car> myCars = new ArrayList<Car>();
myCars.add(ford);
myCars.add(honda);
```

**HERE IS MY PROBLEM:**
When I do `myCars.get(0)` I get an object of class `Car` (obviously) and am never able to get the custom field **radio**.  Of course I could do something like `((Ford) myCars.get(0))` and will be able to see the **radio** field, but is it possible to create a better container what would reveal all of the fields without downcasting etc, something like:
`myContainer.get(0)` - would return the **Ford** class and I would have an access to weight, color and **radio**
`myContainer.get(1)` - would return the **Honda** class and I would have an access to weight, color and **camera**.

My hunch tells me that the solution is near and it is possible, but my expertise in Java is not up there yet.  Maybe I have do to some sort of generics or hashmaps??

Thank you guys!!

Comment: Refer to Effective Java by Joshua Bloch, Item 29: typesafe heterogeneous containers.

Comment: thanks I will look into that!!  at this point of time I do not know much on heterogeneous containers.  Thanks for the lead!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several alternatives, none of which perfectly meets your ideal.

- You could add all the getters for specific properties in your `Car` class and either return `Null` or throw an exception where they are not applicable.
- You could apply the [Visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern).
- You could create a `CarContainer` class that wraps your list and has methods that return all the elements of a specific type, e.g. `List<Ford> getAllTheFords()`. In this way you can hide the ugly casts in your container class.

I listed alternatives according to my personal preference :-)

Comment: Thanks a quick response!!
Just to make sure I understand Item #1 in your list, let me present an example: so in my Car class I would have two properies and three methods then, right?

something like this:

`public abstract class Car{

  private double weight; 
  private String color;
  public Car(){
    this.weight=0;
    this.color="";
  }

// --- GETTERS
public double getWeight(){...}

public String getColor(){...}

public String getRadio(){...}
}`

and what you are saying is that getRadio() method will see the car.radio property.  Am I understanding correctly? Thanks!!

Comment: @JavaFan: only if Car does have a radio attribute. You can either move it there and make it Null for cars that do not have radios, or make Car.getRadio() return Null directly.

Comment: so in an essense, I would have to include all of the attributues for Ford, Honda, Toyota, etc under one roof, which is Car abstract class,   Correct?

Comment: If not the attributes, at least the corresponding getters, yes. In a way it's up to you to choose whether you consider the radio to be a configurable property of all cars or a structural property of Fords alone. In the former case my first solution would be appropriate, otherwise the other ones are probably better.

Comment: In my case, I think it would have to be a structural property of Fords alone. Would you recommend item #3 on your original response as the best solution?

Comment: The Visitor pattern is probably cleaner, but also more complicated. I can't say I like my solution no. 3, but in the end it's probably what I'd use.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is to use generics.

Your repository could implement these methods:

```
public static <T extends Car> T getFromRepository(Class<T> type, Object key) 
public static <T extends Car> boolean addToRepository(Class<T> type, Object key, T value)
```

You could then call this with something like (presuming you already have the key for a Ford):

```
Ford ford = Repository.getFromRepository(Ford.class, fordKey)
```

Of course you can implement methods to get all the objects for a given type and so on...

PS: A simple alternative, if you can use the same method on the sub classes is the template method pattern:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

Answer (score 1):

`myCars.get(0)` does return a Ford object. Except that this is only known at runtime. The problem is that to call `car.radio`, you need to know that it's a Ford and if it's not you can't call that method. So in any case you need to check the type and cast.

One solution would be to add a `List<Accessory>` field to your abstract class.

You can now write something like:

```
Car car = cars.get(0);
if (car.hasAccessories()) {
    car.getAccessory(0).operate();
}
```

Not sure if that's what you need for your use case.

Comment: Thanks!!  I will explore this option.  so what you are saying is that I have crate an Accessory class that will have all of the possible accessories as properties, then use that as a field in the Car object, right?